# How big should i make my assets for a game

Tags: mesh, blend-files, polycount

So, i am trying to make a small game level to test some stuff and I made a tree that is 4.7 million tris, is this way too much and do i need to reduce the size, or is this ok[image]

Comment: 4.7 million tris is way, way to high for most systems. Like *waaay* to high, I'd recommend aiming for around 2k max for a tree that is used many times in an environment.

Comment: top of the line AAA games these days will have for the main character ~0.5m tops. 4.7m for an asset is ***way*** to much. But the exact number depends entirely on your target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that could be ok if the only thing you're going to do in your game is showing this tree alone... and some engines would probably break the same...
A basic character (human mesh + clothes) for vg is good at, lets' say, 15K polys on low-end mobile devices...
To keep a 4M model high quality you need to create a low poly model, then bake all the maps your game engine needs to use the low poly like an high poly, saving processing power in your game engine.

This is called baking and is better explained on Polycount [here](http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Texture_Baking).
Blender-wise, you could try to use the [AssetGen](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?445545-Addon-AssetGen-Create-a-game-asset-in-a-single-click) addon, for instance, to test the process...